# Why is Type the kind of types with values?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

If I enable `MagicHash`, then I have unlifted values such as `42#` with type `Int#`.

Now if [`Type` is the kind of types with values](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Types.html#t:Type), then the kind of `Int#` should be `Type`, but it isn't because `Type` is a synonym for `TYPE 'LiftedRep` whereas the kind of `Int#` is `TYPE 'IntRep`. We can easily confirm this in `ghci`,

```hs
Prelude> :set -XMagicHash -XKindSignatures
Prelude> :m +Data.Kind GHC.Prim
Prelude Data.Kind GHC.Prim> :k (Int# :: Type)

<interactive>:1:2: error:
    • Expecting a lifted type, but ‘Int#’ is unlifted
    • In the type ‘(Int# :: Type)’
```

So is it just the case that we don't regard magic literals such as `42#` as values?

Comment: "So is it just the case that we don't regard magic literals such as 42# as values?" that would be a pretty silly/useless thing to assert. So I think the comment on `Type` is just imprecise/inaccurate.

Comment: `42#` is indeed value. If you think that the documentation can be improved, you can open an issue to GHC.

Comment: I believe the "the kind of types with values" phrase is mainly used in opposition to "incomplete" types like `Maybe` or `Either Int`, or to type-level structures like `'[Int,Bool,Char]` which (in current Haskell) don't have values at the term level. If we include kinds like `TYPE 'IntRep` the phrase is no longer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed turned out to be a deficiency in the documentation and [is now fixed](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/commit/9a1dbefc2723df2c341a0c565b693a4eb8b26195) in GHC's HEAD.

To sum up, `Type` is the kind of types with lifted values because there are other values with differently kinded types such as `42# :: (Int# :: TYPE 'IntRep))`.

Answer (score 2):

Just elide the type signature and GHCI will happily tell you:

```
Prelude Data.Kind GHC.Prim> :k Int#
Int# :: TYPE 'GHC.Types.IntRep
```

It's an unlifted Int, which is about what we'd expect from the name `Int#`.

Comment: That much I know, my objection is to `Type` being the kind of values, where `42#` looks like a value to me.

Comment: @Madgen It is an *unlifted* value, which is treated differently by the compiler than lifted values, and has different kind for that reason. `Int#` is simply not of kind `Type`.